# Replace characters in a dict - Python 3

Tags: python, dictionary

I am working with Python 3 and I want to replace the emoticons included in a dictionary.

For example

```
text = "Hi, I'm coming home :)"

#Create dictionary
dict_lookup = {':(' : 'sad',
               ':)' : 'happy'}
```

The desired output is:

```
Hi, I'm coming home happy
```

What is the most efficient way to achieve this result in Python 3?

Comment: `text.replace(':)', dict_lookup[text[-2:]])`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
for emote, replacement in dict_lookup.items():
      text = text.replace(emote, replacement)
```

Comment: Does it make sense to use Regular Expression (re) in this case?

Comment: @Alex for such use cases `replace()` is always enough. Regular expressions come into play when you can't find the substring that you want to replace with a simple comparison.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `str.replace`

It allows you to do `text.replace(dict_key, dict_value)`